# Getting A cannot Add or Update Child: a foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, sql

I am getting this error when trying to insert in my information into my SQL. I of course know where it is coming from but I don't see where I am not putting in a wrong value.

Below is all of my coding,

```
CREATE TABLE Customer (
CustomerID integer NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
LName varchar(200),
FName varchar(200),
StreetAdd varchar(200),
AptNum integer,
City varchar(100),
State varchar(100),
Zip integer,
HPhone bigint,
MPhone bigint,
OPhone bigint,
PRIMARY KEY (CustomerID));

CREATE TABLE Donut(
  DonutID integer NOT NULL,
  Name varchar(100),
  Description varchar(200),
  UnitPrice float(2),
  PRIMARY KEY (DonutID));


CREATE TABLE DOrder (
OrderID integer NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
OrderDate timestamp,
Notes varchar(400),
CustomerID integer,
PRIMARY KEY(OrderID),
FOREIGN KEY (CustomerID) REFERENCES Customer(CustomerID));

CREATE TABLE Invoice(
  Quantity smallint,
  OrderID integer NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  DonutID integer NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(DonutID, OrderID),
  FOREIGN KEY (OrderID) REFERENCES DOrder(OrderID),
  FOREIGN KEY (DonutID) REFERENCES Donut(DonutID));



INSERT INTO Customer (LName, FName, StreetAdd, City, State, Zip, HPhone)
VALUES ('Roberts','Tammy','3210 Shale Hollow Drive','Evansville','IN',47720, 8888888888);

INSERT INTO Donut (DonutID, Name, Description, UnitPrice)
VALUES (3,'ChocoSprinkle','Chocolate Icing with sprinkles',1.50);

INSERT INTO DOrder (Notes)
VALUES ('include plates and napkins');

INSERT INTO Invoice (OrderID, DonutID, Quantity)
VALUES (1,1,1);
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: Should have more errors than that.  Cant put value into timestamp column, inserting nulls where they are not allowed...

Comment: nope thats the only error it had. there was no issue before I had to redo the two FK's in the Invoice table and declaring the PK in the Invoice table. We are just focusing on the issue with the constraint error everything else is fine.

Comment: I have added auto increments to orderid, customerid and i was able to get rid of the error but now I have an error that says OrderID has no default value. This should on its own start at 1. I do not have to declare that into the insert value

Comment: In the update code now you insert a donut with the id of 3 only. Then you insert in the invoice table a record where you specify 1 as the donut id and you are suprised that it does not work. **Provide existing values from donut and order tables as ids in the invoice table, and you will not get foreign key errors. This is what toreign keys are ment to ensure!**

Comment: When you insert into TABLE `DOrder`, DOrder.CustomerID should be assigned to a number existing in TABLE Customer.CustomerID because DOrder.CustomerID is a foreign key reffers to Customer.CustomerID

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the last insert: you are not providing any values for the 2 foreign keys. Those 2 columns should not be made auto increment, you should provide explicit values for them that already exist in the 2 other tables:

```
INSERT INTO Invoice (OrderID, DonutID, Quantity)
VALUES (1,1,1);
```

Furthermore, if you declared a field a numeric type, such as integer, then pls do not insert a string into it, but a number, as I showed in the above example.

Comment: thank you, I believe i dont have any with strings coming into a numeric type.

Comment: with the addition of your code I am still getting the error.

Comment: sorry i forgot to attach the full error in my last comment Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db_9_8673fa`.`invoice`, CONSTRAINT `invoice_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`DonutID`) REFERENCES `donut` (`DonutID`))

Comment: Yes, you do. In every single insert query you included in your question.

Comment: Then check what values you have in the donuts and orders tables as the ids. Based on your insert queries, you should have record with id=1 in both tables.

Comment: ok i have taken those out though they did not pose a problem before like previously stated the code you had me insert did not do anything it is still pulling the error of the references

Answer (score -1):

In the sentence

```
INSERT INTO Invoice (Quantity)
VALUES ('1');
```

... there are no explicit values for the `OrderID` and `DonutID` columns. And, since they both are of numeric type, the MySql engine is assuming the proper automatic default values. In this case, the default numeric value is 0.

So, when it tries to match the new Invoice row it against the parent tables, it searches a `Donut` with `DonutId`=0 and a `DOrder` with `OrderId`=0. Since there are no such rows, it produces the error you get.

Want one more clue? Try to insert both an `Order` with `DOrderId`=0 and a `Donut` with `DonutId`=0 and then re-try your `INSERT INTO Invoice (Quantity) VALUES ('1')`. See it success.

Best practice is always provide explicit non-null values for PK columns (and also define PK columns as `NOT NULL`).

Comment: Hello, I think i understand what you mean sorry i'm extremely new to SQL. I have updated the code up top the order ID is suppose to be auto increment (sorry i was fiddling around with my code when i decided to upload) Do I have to have them be the same number?

Comment: ACTUALLY THE MOMENT I TOOK BACK YOUR INFORMATION I GOT IT TOO WORK!!

Comment: my happiness is overwhelming it took me two weeks to figure this out lol

Comment: Mine too, then. :-)

Comment: " And, since they both are of numeric type, the MySql engine is assuming the proper automatic default values." - no, mysql will not assume a default value automatically, unless you define a default value to a field in the create table.

Comment: @Shadow Test it by yourself: Adding both parent rows with id=0 is enough to make that INSERT work. How do you explain it?

Comment: That you have either strict sql mode turned off and mysql interpreted the null value as 0 and issued a warning only, or you did specify a default value in your create table. With strict sql mode turned on (as should be) no default value and not null constraint (donutid of the invoice table), you would get an error message.

Comment: @Shadow Well my `sql_mode` now is `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`. Have you tried yourself with the schema from the OP?

Comment: Yes, I did and I got the error message that is also mentioned by the OP (no default value).

Comment: "For data entry into a NOT NULL column that has no explicit DEFAULT clause, if an INSERT or REPLACE statement includes no value for the column, or an UPDATE statement sets the column to NULL, MySQL handles the column according to the SQL mode in effect at the time:

If strict SQL mode is enabled, an error occurs for transactional tables and the statement is rolled back. For nontransactional tables, an error occurs, but if this happens for the second or subsequent row of a multiple-row statement, the preceding rows will have been inserted."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122947/discussion-between-little-santi-and-shadow).